# Fastest way to convert int to 4 bytes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, bit-manipulation

What is a fastest way to convert int to 4 bytes in C# ?

Fastest as in execution time not development time.

My own solution is this code:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
unchecked
{
 bytes[0] = (byte)(data >> 24);
 bytes[1] = (byte)(data >> 16);
 bytes[2] = (byte)(data >> 8);
 bytes[3] = (byte)(data);
}
```

Right now I see that my solution outperforms both `struct` and `BitConverter` by couple of ticks.

I think the unsafe is probably the fastest option and accept that as an answer but I would prefer to use a managed option.

Comment: By `fastest` do you mean a) least amount of code or b) best performance?

Comment: 'Fastest' depends on where you want those bytes to go.

Comment: How much memory do you have? If the integers are all +ve and the range of values isn't huge, how about a lookup array? (not sure that'll be faster than one bitshift though).

Comment: It not applicable in my case but it is original :).

Comment: Interesting, BUT: have you tried reordering and shifitng the data "again". I can see this going with 3 x >> 8 only (total 24 shifts) instead of your 48.

Comment: I don't think I understood your suggestion

Comment: @TomTom that would only be worse. There is no such thing as "total shifts" - shifting by any offset is a single cycle operation. But there would suddenly be a data dependency, precluding superscalar executing.

Comment: good catch. very interesting. i did not know that assembler level any shift number is single operation. One always learns ;)

Comment: For reference, as stated in the [C# Language Specification, Shift Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):
Shift operations never cause overflows and produce the same results in checked and unchecked contexts.

So the unchecked statement in the question is overkill.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A byte* cast using unsafe code is by far the fastest:

```
    unsafe static void Main(string[] args) {
        int i = 0x12345678;
        byte* pi = (byte*)&i;
        byte lsb = pi[0];  
        // etc..
    }
```

That's what BitConverter does as well, this code avoids the cost of creating the array.

Comment: ;) actually it is unsafe - and this is not needed ;) Really. Anotehr safe (!) solution has a similar speed.

Comment: Yes, that's why it uses the *unsafe* keyword.  Which is pretty much available to do exactly this, write fast code.  The OP's request was for *fast*, not *similar*.

Comment: Interesting enough that does not change the fact that for this particular problem there is a solution that is as fast and SAFE. Ergo the unsafe solution is worse. This is different for other problems, but this particular one would get a second place in a review from me for unsafe code - passed, please rewrite.

Comment: I'd have to guess that you don't work for Microsoft.  The trouble with methods that contain structs is that they don't get inlined.  At least BitConverter.GetBytes() gets inlined.

Comment: I did once as consultant actually - SQL Server level 3 support. These days I do a lot of stuff moving some minor data amounts, mostly financial data, which comes in byte coded form. When you bulk load hundreds of millions of rows as fast as possible you start really pushing for speed.

Comment: It can be perfectly safe to use `unsafe`, provided you can run in a trusted context, and as long as there's some way to indicate that it could be unsafe if not examined carefully. Like having the word "unsafe" somewhere near the code as a sort of indicator.

Comment: This does not seem correct according to my investigations, the fastest way is really assignment with the shift as the author of the question suggested (and it also allows you to do big/little endianess). This is fastest for long though, please see my answer for details and comparison.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Maybe the author meant to ask for the shortest, coolest, *awesomest* way to convert that ;)

Comment: Is the cost of creating the array actually that high? Is there any noticeable performance improvement by removing it?

Answer (score 19):

> What is a fastest way to convert int to 4 bytes in C# ?

Using a [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter_methods.aspx) and it's [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) overload that takes a 32 bit integer:

```
int i = 123;
byte[] buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
```

Comment: @TomTom: Would unsafe be faster or something then?

Comment: You are probably forgetting the fact that BitConverter.GetBytes uses unsafe code to directly access the memory address where the integer is stored and is uber fast.

Comment: Look at my answer. no method is needed. BitConverter is flexbile which means slow. Converting bytes to int does not require any logic or method call, only an understanding of how - well - structs with explicit layout work. Unsafe has it's uses, but there is a safe solution here using a union struct. Same speed.

Comment: @TomTom, interesting solution. But if it's similar speed I prefer a BCL method call which is also shorter and less error prone. You don't need to mark your assembly as unsafe as BitConverter.GetBytes is a BCL method. I agree, it is unsafe. As are unsafe enormously lots of methods in the BCL that we are using all the time.

Comment: Error prone: no difference. And well, you may prefer the slower method, but this does not change the fact that your answer is wrong - the poster explicitly asked for the FASTEST way. ONLY speed. Even ease of use was explicitly taken off the decision matrix.

Comment: @TomTom, OK, I am not going to argue with you. Neither you are going to make me change my mind, neither I am going to make you change your mind. So I prefer not to continue this discussion as it is getting pointless to me. I have exposed my solution and you have exposed yours and I respect yours. That's why Stack Overflow is a great place. Because we can see different approaches to tackle problems. I think that the community can only benefit from this diversity.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: FYI, edited my post with speed test (in `BitConverter`'s favour).

Comment: Your solution does not take into consideration that usually you need to write to an existing array. And in this case BitConverter is much slower as you have to create a new array and then copy it. Please take a look at my answer, I have made comparison of different methods.

Answer (score 16):

The fastest way is with a struct containing 4 bytes.

- In a defined layout (at  byte position 0, 1, 2, 3
- And an int32 that starts at position 0.
- Put in the 4 variables, read out the byte.
- Finished.

Significantly faster than the BitConverter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx

has the necessary attribute.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct FooUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte byte0;
    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte byte1;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte byte2;
    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte byte3;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int integer;

}
```

Comment: I like cleverness of your solution

Comment: Me too...  I just wish it were easier to read (the answer, not the code) and had some benchmarks with it.  +1 anyway

Comment: Clean, simple, easy to understand. I couldn't care about performance when code is this bullet proof. ++

Comment: This code is perfect if you are not just converting bytes, but need to have both the packed and unpacked values available for later.  For example, storing R,G,B, and Alpha `byte` values packed in to an `int` when working with colors.

Comment: This is an amazing technique I've never considered/seen before. ++

Answer (score 13):

I have done a research on the times needed to serialize a basic type to byte array. I did it for the case when you already have an array and offset where you want to put your data. I guess that's really an important case compared to theoretical get an array of 4 bytes because when you are serializing something then it's exactly what you need. I have figured out that the answer to what method is faster depends on what type you want to serialize. I have tried few methods:

1. Unsafe reference with an additional buffer overrun check
2. GetBytes + consequent Buffer.BulkCopy (This is essentially the same as 1 plus overhead)
3. Direct assignment with shift (
       `m_Bytes[offset] = (byte)(value >> 8)`
4. Direct assignment with shift and bitwise & 
       `m_Bytes[offset] = (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xFF)`

I ran all of the test 10 mln times. Below are the results in milliseconds

```
      Long   Int   Short  Byte   Float   Double
1     29     32     31     30     29      34
2     209    233    220    212    208     228
3     63     24     13     8      24      44
4     72     29     14
```

As you can see the unsafe way is much faster for long and double (unsigned versions are about the same as their signed versions so they are not in the table). For short/int/float the fastest way is the 2/4/4 assignments with shift. For byte the fastest is obviously the simple assignment. So regarding the original question - the assignment way is the best. This is the example of such a function in a fastest way:

```
    public static void WriteInt(byte[] buffer, int offset, int value)
    {
        m_BytesInt[offset] = (byte)(value >> 24);
        m_BytesInt[offset + 1] = (byte)(value >> 16);
        m_BytesInt[offset + 2] = (byte)(value >> 8);
        m_BytesInt[offset + 3] = (byte) value;
    }
```

P.S. The tests were run on x64 environment with code compiled to cpu any (which was x64 on run) in release mode.

Comment: Would ++offset speed this up a bit?

Comment: @Karussell You might be correct I have not thought about it for some reason, but you can check it and share the results here :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik How is approach #3 (direct assignment with shift) accomplished with a float? I didn't think bit shifting a float was possible. in C#  Did you use unsafe for float?

Comment: I think you are right, but I honestly don't remember anymore what I did in there :) Perhaps I did use unsafe as you say.

Answer (score 7):

**Note the BitConverter may not be the fastest as the test below shows.**

Use the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) class, specifically the [`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx) method that takes an [`Int32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) parameter:

```
var myInt = 123;
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(myInt);
```

You can use [`BitConverter.IsLittlEndian`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) to determine the byte order based on the CPU architecture.

---

**EDIT: The test below isn't conclusive due to compiler optimisations.**

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct FooUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte byte0;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte byte1;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte byte2;
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte byte3;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int integer;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testUnion();
            testBitConverter();

            Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();

            Timer.Start();
            testUnion();
            Timer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(Timer.ElapsedTicks);

            Timer = new Stopwatch();

            Timer.Start();
            testBitConverter();
            Timer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(Timer.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void testBitConverter()
        {
            byte[] UnionBytes;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UnionBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
            }
        }

        static void testUnion()
        {
            byte[] UnionBytes;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                FooUnion union = new FooUnion() { integer = i };

                UnionBytes = new byte[] { union.byte0, union.byte1, union.byte2, union.byte3 };

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Too slow, sorry. There are faster methods not involving any method.

Comment: See my edit for a speed test, not sure if i've made a mistake, but don't think so. It shows BitConverter is faster if you need an array (although not exactly much in it).

Comment: And where in the original post does it say there is an array in the start? It says 4 bytes. I use the struct offset for financial market data handling (5 bytes in an 8 byte struct - 4 bytes tick count, 1 byte tick coding). Ridiculously fast.

Comment: You can safely assume there is no array, which adds creating the array and garbage collection as overhead as per OP specs.

Comment: Copied your code and ran (Release build), and `BitConverter` was slower by almost 10x.  If I run a Debug build, I see times that are similar between the two.

Comment: @TomTom: He's edited his question to show he needs an array, although apparently his solution is better than all of ours (lol).

Comment: @adrift:You are right, I stand corrected (although not sure what's been optimised out).

Comment: @adrift, the reason you are seeing this is because in Release mode, the compiler has optimized the code and removed the `UnionBytes = new byte[] { union.byte0, union.byte1, union.byte2, union.byte3 };` line from the MSIL rendering the union solution useless. That's why it is 10x faster in Release mode. Because it never runs.

Comment: Looks like the moral is, implement each one in real code and test there.

Comment: @George Duckett I don't necessary need array

Comment: It's slow because you are simply allocating an array instance again and again with the union method, which is no different from what BitConverter is doing.

If you reused the array's instance and simply reassigned it's cels with the respective bytes of the new union instance, then we might see an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

As many in here seem to argue about if `BitConverter` is beter than a dedicated `struct`. Based on BCL source code the `BitConverter.GetBytes()` looks like this:

```
public static unsafe byte[] GetBytes(int value)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    fixed (byte* bufferRef = buffer)
    {
        *((int*)bufferRef) = value;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Which from my point of view is more clean and seems faster than making 1 integer + 4 byte assignments to a explicit struct as this one.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct IntByte
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int IntVal;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte Byte0;
  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public byte Byte1;
  [FieldOffset(2)]
  public byte Byte2;
  [FieldOffset(3)]
  public byte Byte3;
}

new IntByte { IntVal = 10 } -> Byte0, Byte1, Byte2, Byte3.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        unsafe{
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
            for(int i = 0; i != int.MaxValue; ++i)
            {
            fixed(byte* asByte = byteArray)
               *((int*)asByte) = 43;
               }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Averages around 2770ms on my machine while

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Switcher
{
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public int intVal;
  [FieldOffset(0)]
  public byte b0;
  [FieldOffset(1)]
  public byte b1;
  [FieldOffset(2)]
  public byte b2;
  [FieldOffset(3)]
  public byte b3;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[4];
        Switcher swi = new Switcher();
        for(int i = 0; i != int.MaxValue; ++i)
        {
          swi.intVal = 43;
          byteArray[0] = swi.b0;
          byteArray[1] = swi.b1;
          byteArray[2] = swi.b2;
          byteArray[3] = swi.b3;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Averages around 4510ms.

Comment: Fake test - fites the new conditions. There was no word originally of an array and you replace a pointer arithmethid with safe boudary code tested arrays - so the test is skewed towards array boundary checking negatively to the struct solution.

Comment: @TomTom Of course it's a fake test, all tests are fake except for that of seeing how it works in real life. In neither does everything get optimised away for one of them, so it serves. We could replace the array copy with placing it into four separate bytes and it still matters that actually getting the bytes to somewhere adds to the struct-based approach. It's a good workaround for cases where you can't use `unsafe`, and it is fast at around half a billion cycles a second as will make no odds.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be the fastest way in C#.. (with byte array initialized to 4x the int stream w/ int32

```
        private MemoryStream Convert(int[] Num, byte[] Bytes)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(Num, 0, Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Bytes);
        return stream;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Union is the fastest way of splitting an integer into bytes. Below is a complete program in which the C# optimizer can't optimize the byte splitting operation out, because each byte is summed and the sum is printed out.

The timings on my laptop are **419 milliseconds for the Union** and **461 milliseconds for the BitConverter**. The speed gain, however, is much greater.

This method is used in an open source high-performance algorithms [HPCsharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HPCsharp/) library, where the Union method provides a nice performance boost for the Radix Sort.

Union is faster because it performs no bitwise masking and no bit-shift, but simply reads the proper byte out of the 4-byte integer.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SplitIntIntoBytes
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct FooUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public byte byte0;
        [FieldOffset(1)]
        public byte byte1;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public byte byte2;
        [FieldOffset(3)]
        public byte byte3;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int integer;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            testUnion();
            testBitConverter();

            Stopwatch Timer = new Stopwatch();

            Timer.Start();
            int sumTestUnion = testUnion();
            Timer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("time of Union:        " + Timer.ElapsedTicks + " milliseconds,  sum: " + sumTestUnion);

            Timer.Restart();
            int sumBitConverter = testBitConverter();
            Timer.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("time of BitConverter: " + Timer.ElapsedTicks + " milliseconds,  sum: " + sumBitConverter);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int testBitConverter()
        {
            byte[] UnionBytes = new byte[4];
            byte[] SumOfBytes = new byte[4];
            SumOfBytes[0] = SumOfBytes[1] = SumOfBytes[2] = SumOfBytes[3] = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                UnionBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
                SumOfBytes[0] += UnionBytes[0];
                SumOfBytes[1] += UnionBytes[1];
                SumOfBytes[2] += UnionBytes[2];
                SumOfBytes[3] += UnionBytes[3];
            }
            return SumOfBytes[0] + SumOfBytes[1] + SumOfBytes[2] + SumOfBytes[3];
        }

        static int testUnion()
        {
            byte[] UnionBytes;
            byte[] SumOfBytes = new byte[4];
            SumOfBytes[0] = SumOfBytes[1] = SumOfBytes[2] = SumOfBytes[3] = 0;

            FooUnion union = new FooUnion();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                union.integer = i;
                UnionBytes = new byte[] { union.byte0, union.byte1, union.byte2, union.byte3 };
                SumOfBytes[0] += UnionBytes[0];
                SumOfBytes[1] += UnionBytes[1];
                SumOfBytes[2] += UnionBytes[2];
                SumOfBytes[3] += UnionBytes[3];
            }
            return SumOfBytes[0] + SumOfBytes[1] + SumOfBytes[2] + SumOfBytes[3];
        }
    }
}
```